# From SAP Data Loading Perspective - What is the difference between R/3 and S/4HANA

Tags: load, s4hana, sap-r3

In the previous R/3 SAP we had BAPI/IDOC/LSMW(standard batch inputs) to load data from legacy systems.

Since S/4HANA has a completely different storage model, minimizing the number of tables etc. Are the BAPIs and IDOCs still relevant in the loading process or can we directly access the underlying tables and load them instead?

I have extremely limited exposure to S/4HANA so would appreciate some useful guidance.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. These features (BAPI/IDOC/LSMW/Batch Inputs) are all available on S/4 Hana.
You can manage as a normal sap system upgrade.